# Minimal and Maximal terms in $A=\{1,2,3,4\}$ and $R$ relation on $\mathcal{P}(A)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have the set $A=\{1,2,3,4\}$ and my relation is on $\mathcal{P}(A)$ where $X\subseteq Y \wedge XRY$
I wrote $\mathcal{P}(A)$ and get
$$\mathcal{P}(A) =\{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,1),(2,3),(2,4),(3,1),(3,2),(3,4),(4,1),(4,2),(4,3)\}$$
my question is if there is minimal or maximal terms in this power set? becuase the definition is that (let say we want the minimal ) for minimal is for all $a\in A \rightarrow xRa$ and there is few minimals terms.
Thanks.

Comment: Note that $\mathcal{P}(A) \neq A \times A$. Recall that $|\mathcal{P}(A)| = 2^{|A|}$.

Comment: why its not equal?

Comment: Adriano,this is equal!
|p(a)|=16

Comment: Their cardinalities happen to be the same ($2^4=4^2$), but that's just a coincidence. The actual elements in each set are different (for example, $(2,3)\in A \times A$ yet $(2,3) \notin \mathcal{P}(A)$, and $\{2,3,4\} \in \mathcal{P}(A)$ yet $\{2,3,4\} \notin A \times A$.

Comment: I don't really understand your ordering relation $R$. Given any two elements of $\mathcal{P}(A)$, how can we determine which is "better" than the other? For example, one possible relation is:
$$
\forall X,Y\in \mathcal{P}(A),~~ XRY \iff X \subseteq Y
$$

Comment: This is completely irrelevant. $\wp(A)\ne A\times A$, which is what the OP wrote. The fact that they have the same cardinality is quite beside the point. (And what you wrote here should have been a comment.)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott what is $\mathcal P(A)$?

Comment: @Ofir: It’s the set of all subsets of $A$. If $A$ were $\{a,b,c\}$, for instance, it would be $$\Big\{\varnothing,\{a\},\{b\},\{c\},\{a,b\},\{a,c\},\{b,c\},\{a,b,c\}\Big\}\;.$$

Comment: $\{ \phi, \{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{4\},\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{1,4\},\{2,3\},\{2,4\},\{3,4\},\{1,2,3,4\}\}$

Comment: I need to add $\{1,2,3\},\{1,2,4\},\{1,3,4\},\{2,3,4\}$?

Comment: @Ofir: Yes, you do; that brings you to $16=2^4$ subsets, which is correct.